# Stuck with receiving user input and then turning it into an Int value

Tags: c#, string, parsing, int

So for class I have to make a little BMI calculator in C# and I'm having some trouble.

So I have 2 textboxes, `weightTxt` for weight and `heightTxt` for height, but I cant seem to get the value the user enters into something I can use for an If-else statement.

This is what i did to convert the string to int:

```
int weight = Int32.Parse(weightTxt.Text);
int height = Int32.Parse(heightTxt.Text);
```

In my mind I think this should turn whatever text is in each box into a int value, no?

Also, side question, in an If statement why cant I do something like this with Int

```
if (weight >= 300 || weight <= 10)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Input not acceptable");
}
```

Thanks a alot, yes i am very noob, pls help me :)

Edit: This is what my entire .cs looks like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int weight = Int32.TryParse(weightTxt.Text);
        int height = Int32.TryParse(heightTxt.Text);

        if (weight >= 300)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Input not acceptable");
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing?
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your code looks fine. Maybe it's being called before the user enters their input.

Comment: Do you receive an error when parsing weightTxt and heightTxt?

Comment: When this code gets executed? On button click or something?

Comment: you'll have to provide more code to get a helpful answer.  Sounds like a scoping issue

Comment: 'this should turn whatever text is in each box into a int value', wrong, will TRY to convert it to an integer, if it's not a numeral string (it contains non-numeric characters) it will throw an exception.

Comment: Use TryParse. the user might not type a number.

Comment: I second what @EricLippert suggested. You should be using TryParse instead to avoid an exception being thrown if the user enters an invalid input.

Comment: @EricLippert TryParse returns an error "No overload for method "TryParse" takes 1 arguments"  ... what do?

Comment: Maybe read the documentation.

Comment: @Gusman yeah i think thats what's happening, the program starts with no errors but once I press the button it says "Unhandled exception in your application, Input string was not in a correct format"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it could be done, using full validation.

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    public void OnButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CalculateAndDisplayBMI();
    }

    private void CalculateAndDisplayBMI()
    {
        int weight = 0;
        int height = 0;

        if(!TryGetWeight(out weight))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid value for weight.")
            return;
        }

        if (!TryGetHeight(out height))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid value for height.")
            return;
        }

        double bmi = CalculateBmi(weight, height);
        bmiTxt.Text = $"{bmi}";
    }

    private bool TryGetWeight(out int weight)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(weightTxt.Text, out weight))
            return false;

        if (weight <= 10 || weight >= 300) // kgs
            return false;
    }

    private bool TryGetHeight(out int height)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(heightTxt.Text, out height))
            return false;

        if (height <= 100 || height >= 250) // cms
            return false;
    }

    private double CalculateBmi(int height, int weight)
    {
        double heightInMeters = height / 100d;
        return weight / (heightInMeters * heightInMeters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parsing is correct!:

```
int weight = Int32.Parse(weightTxt.Text);
int height = Int32.Parse(heightTxt.Text);
```

You can do something like this:

```
if (weight >= 300 || weight <= 10)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Input not acceptable");
}
```

**unless** the variable `weight` is declared as a local variable in another method! For example:

```
void method1()
{
    int weight = Int32.Parse(weightTxt.Text);
    int height = Int32.Parse(heightTxt.Text);
}
```

you will not be able to use it in `method2` because it does not exist in this scope:

```
void method2()
{
    if (weight >= 300 || weight <= 10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Input not acceptable");
    }
}
```

The solution to this problem would be to declare the variable at class level!

```
class Form1 : Form
{

    int weight;
    int height;
```

and use the variable through the class. But beware not to declare them again!

```
    void method1()
    {
        weight = Int32.Parse(weightTxt.Text);
        height = Int32.Parse(heightTxt.Text);
    } 

    void method2()
    {
        if (weight >= 300 || weight <= 10)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Input not acceptable");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the only error seems to be the use of TryParse.
Please lookup the signature of the method:

```
int weight;
Int32.TryParse(weightTxt.Text,out weight);
int height;
Int32.TryParse(heightTxt.Text,out height);
```